# jQuery Wrap a strike After, Append or Regex?

Tags: jquery, regex, append

I want to add a strike tag through JUST the price characters of a font tag with class 'specialprice'. It is hard because of the way the code is set up to JUST get the Price and not the text before it:

What if I could wrap everything in a strike in 'specialprice' AFTER font.colors_text or NOT font.colors_text, something like that?

I have this:

```
<font class="pricecolor colors_productprice specialprice">
   <font class="text colors_text">
      <b>Regular Price:<br></b>
   </font>
   $2,492<sup>.38</sup>
</font>
```

I want this:

```
<font class="pricecolor colors_productprice specialprice">
   <font class="text colors_text">
      <b>Regular Price:<br></b>
   </font>
   <strike>$2,492<sup>.38</sup></strike>
</font>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using `<font>` tags?  `<span>` seems more semantically correct in this case.

Comment: I agree, unfortunately it is what it is with my shopping cart =p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS, add a class for strikethroughs:

```
.strike {text-decoration: line-through;}
```

And in your jQuery:

```
// get all the children of pricecolor, filter out the colors_text children,
// and wrap the span of price around them
$(".pricecolor").contents().each(function() {
    if(!$(this).is(".colors_text")) {
        $(this).wrap("<span class='price'>");
    }
});

$(".price").addClass("strike");
```

For the selector of your price to strikethrough you may want to use an ID, giving each price a unique ID, if you have many prices on the page.

Comment: This of course makes sense.  I would need to use jQuery to add a span tag to JUST the price though, how could this be done?

Comment: @ToddN - edited my answer, and you can [see it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/Xn7YN/2/) over at jsfiddle.

Comment: This works partially.  It is different in Firefox (spans whole text), chrome (works perfectly), IE (nothing).

Comment: @ToddN - that's funny, works in the version of Firefox I'm using.  Does the jsfiddle link I provided work in all browsers for you?  If so, maybe something is different in the HTML  or version of jQuery?

Comment: @justkt ok Just verified, your link works fine in FF and Chrome, but nothing in IE still.

Comment: @ToddN - I don't have easy access to IE right now or an intuitive idea of why, but what's the debug say?

Comment: I am trying a different way to do this.  I want to wrap around the next elements AFTER the text 'Regular Price:'.  Something like this but it doesnt work yet: `$('.colors_text').each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/Regular Price:.*$/, '<span class="strike">$&</span>'));
});`

Comment: @ToddN - Don't select .colors_text.  You need to get the text node of .pricecolor (because jQuery's .next() grabs the next non-text node).

Answer (score 0):

jQuery.wrap is the thing I would use if I cannot change the HTML to begin with.

Try this (not tested though)

First get all parts that should be striked, then use `.wrap($("<strike></strike>"))` on the elements.

```
var list = $("span.pricecolor").children();
list.not(list.first());
list.wrap($("<strike></strike>"));
```

Comment: Or just `$("span.pricecolor").children(':gt(0)').wrap('<strike />');` (The above will not work as-is, since `list` is not changed in-place; it will always point to `$("span.pricecolor").children()`. The intention, however, is sound.)

Comment: Top Part: puts strike through the Regular Price and the Superscript.  The bottom part wraps a strike only through the Superscript.

Answer (score 0):

Due to inconsistences among browsers in accessing children elements, you can use Regex instead:

```
$(".specialprice").html($(".specialprice").html().replace(/<\/font>(.*<\/sup>)/i, "</font><strike>$1</strike>"));
```

Comment: hmm thanks for the response however this did not do anything, is there something I am mmissing?